# Google Maps Android - Disable pin dropping on map touch

Tags: android, google-maps

How do I disable a new pin being dropped when a user touches the map?  This seems like this should be obvious, but I can't find it anywhere!  Basically map comes up with my custom pins, user touches anywhere on the screen, a dummy pin appears and mine disappear.

Comment: That's not default behavior. Could you post the code relevant to your maps implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the [draggable(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#draggable(boolean)) function in markerOptions, you can set the draggable to be false.

For more information about a draggable market, you can visit [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#make_a_marker_draggable).

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb.  I got a little copy and paste happy and had that as part of a listener.

Answer (score 0):

On my Android if I put a location in the search bar and touch the screen the search information goes away and all I see is the map, no pin dropping. However if I touched the current location button, every time I touch the screen it drops a pin and the search information stays on the screen.